# Add <style> element to an HTML using Python Dominate library

Tags: python, html, css, dominate

I'm trying to generate an HTML with the dominate package in Python. For the format, I have to add a short CSS content into the `<style>` tag. However, the only documentation I can find is the GitHub page and that page doesn't have any function related to adding the `<style>`.

PS: Here's an image

[image]

Comment: Please provide a clear example of what you would like the output to look like.

Comment: @SteveJ Thanks for reminding. I got the post updated. The 5 images I have should be in a horizontal row.

Comment: I should have been more clear, sorry. What is the resulting raw html that you would like to see dominate produce?

Comment: @SteveJ I think my raw html is fine because I inserted your <head> section into my original html and the result was very close to what I want--align all the images side by side; the only difference is that I want the 5 images are aligned horizontally in a row, not vertically.

Comment: That your images are horizontal, not vertical isn't a function of dominate and not directly relevant to the question as I understand it. First, you need to make your html work as you want it - then post the html here. Only then can we help you modify the dominate code to produce your desired html. The problem is that nobody reading this question understands what dominate isn't doing for you that you want it to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you are after? [from here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/98153/dominate.document)

```
import dominate
from dominate.tags import link, script, style

doc = dominate.document(title='Dominate your HTML')

with doc.head:
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='style.css')
    script(type='text/javascript', src='script.js')
    style("""\
         body {
             background-color: #F9F8F1;
             color: #2C232A;
             font-family: sans-serif;
             font-size: 2.6em;
             margin: 3em 1em;
         }

     """)

print(doc.render(pretty=True))
```

It yields;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dominate your HTML</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>         body {
             background-color: #F9F8F1;
             color: #2C232A;
             font-family: sans-serif;
             font-size: 2.6em;
             margin: 3em 1em;
         }

     </style>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added style from a string but dominate escaped all " with &quot; How to prevent this?

Comment: @AzureIP: I believe you are asking a different question than the original. In such case, it deserves its own SO question. If you ask it as a new question, I'm certain you will get the help you need.